# PowerShell - continue if string is not contained in file (detect when a cmdlet returns nothing)

Tags: powershell, null, comparison

I am searching for a string (`$Loan_Id`) in a file (`$File_LoanData`). I am able to find it, but should the string not be found, I need the script to continue. That does not seem to be working. Here is the problem line -- 
`if ($Note_Line -eq $false)   {Continue}`

```
$Fie_LCExtract = "c:\temp\Fie_LCExtract.txt"
$File_LoanData = "c:\temp\File_LoanData.txt"
$File_LoanDataToday = "c:\temp\File_LoanDataToday.txt"
$r = [IO.File]::OpenText($Fie_LCExtract)
while ($r.Peek() -ge 0) 
    {
     $Note = $r.ReadLine()
     $Loan_Id = ($Note -split ';')[0].trim()
     $Loan_Id = $Loan_Id -as [int]
     if (($Loan_Id -is [int])  -eq $false) {Continue}
     $Note_Line = Select-String -Path $File_LoanData -Pattern $Loan_Id
     if ($Note_Line -eq $false)   {Continue}
     $Note_Line =  ($Note_Line -split ':')[3].trim()
     $Note_Line  >> $File_LoanDataToday
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't compare to `$False`**, use the return value directly as if it were a Boolean:

```
if (-not $Note_Line) { Continue }
```

Alternatively, compare to `$null`:

```
if ($null -eq $Note_Line) { Continue }
```

Or use the `.Count` property:

```
if ($Note_Line.Count -eq 0) { Continue }
```

`Select-String` returns a "null collection" ("nothing") when it finds no matches and this special value (`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`) is "falsy" in a Boolean context; also, it is considered equal to `$null` and its `.Count` property is always `0`.

**However, despite a null collection *implicitly* being considered `$False`, comparing it *explicitly* to `$False` does *not* yield `$True`**:

The **null collection is treated like `$null` in an expression context**, and **the only value that `$null` equals (`-eq`) is `$null` itself**<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
$null -eq $False # !! $False
$null -eq $null  # $True
```

Using a null collection / `$null` *implicitly* as a Boolean is equivalent to casting it to `[bool]`, so we can see that it is "falsy":

```
[bool] $null  # $False
```

---

<sup>[1] This applies to using `$null` *as the LHS* of `-eq`. As the RHS,
 if the LHS is array-valued, it act as a *filter* and returns the sub-array of elements containing `$null`.

For instance, `$null, 1, $null -eq $null` returns a 2-element array of `$null` values.</sup>

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot.